# Reloading or refreshing a UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

My app allows a user to unlock a bunch of levels with an in app purchase. To indicate that a level is locked, I change the icon alpha to 0.7, just to differentiate it from levels they own/can access.

My code works by checking the NSUserDefaults for a BOOL key on viewDidLoad:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"com.productbundle.unlock"]){
    //set these levels to alpha = 0.7
}
```

So after they successfully purchase, it would be really easy if I could just refresh/reload the UIView. Is there a way to do this? Or is there alternate way I can achieve this affect? Thanks

Comment: I can run [self viewDidLoad] which sort of works, it redraws the elements correctly but the old elements still appear underneath. So I tried adding in [self viewDidDisappear] and [self viewDidUnload] before running viewDidLoad but they didn't work. I also tried [self setNeedsDisplay] but that doesn't work.

Comment: Don't do that. Changing a view's alpha doesn't require further actions. If a view needs re-drawing, send it `setNeedsDisplay`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be calling [self viewDidLoad].  As I understand it those are more methods you implement in your subclass to respond to various events and in general you shouldn't call them yourself.  Looking more at the documentation for views, if you want to refresh stuff when a view becomes visible again look into implementing

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

viewWillAppear = "Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be become visible."

I'd check for your user defaults, and stick an if statement in there:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([defaults boolForKey:@"com.productbundle.unlock"] == YES) {
            //set alpha to 1
        };


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the setNeedsDisplay to refresh a UIView.

```
[yourUIView setNeedsDisplay];
```